# Exception when calling FileStream.SetLength method on a network share from Ventura

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, macos-ventura

I'm experiencing a strange problem with a netcore 6.0 app. I open a filestream on a file located on a Samba network share, from a MAC.

Everything worked fine until the update to Ventura.

Here is a very simple code to reproduce:

```
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filePath = "/Volumes/common/_jq-share/files/test/Database-journal.db";
            var stream = new FileStream (filePath, 
                    FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, 4096);
   
            stream.SetLength(stream.Length);     // No exception
            stream.SetLength(stream.Length + 1); // Exception is raised here
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, whenever we use `SetLength` in order to increase the file size, then it will crash with the following error:

```
Input/output error : '/Volumes/someNetworkShare/myDatabase.db' (HResult: 5)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.CheckFileCall(Int64 result, String path, Boolean ignoreNotSupported)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.SetFileLength(SafeFileHandle handle, Int64 length)
   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy.SetLengthCore(Int64 value)
   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy.SetLength(Int64 value)
   at System.IO.FileStream.SetLength(Int64 value)
   at Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in /.../Program.cs:line 14
```

As mentioned earlier, this error is only thrown when running the program from a MacOS Ventura.

I tried to retrieve the version of the Samba protocol used, with the following command:

```
smbutil statshares -m /Volumes/someNetworkShare/|grep VERSION|awk '{print $2}'
```

On all Mac with Ventura, the result is SMB_3.1.1, whereas on older MacOS OSes (such as BigSur) it is SMB_3.02. Could it have any influence?

Is this a bug in .net 6?

There is no funny business on the server such as access right problem or whatsoever.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried other dotnet versions? Both older and newer could help narrow it down if you are capable, but it might not help at all.

Comment: Another idea - reduce the file size by one then increase it again.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b, I tried with netcore 6 and 7 and to first reduce the file size, but sadly none of them worked.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. It is likely a problem with dotnet.